# Worklight Adapter Unable to find certificate chain

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a worklight project with an adapter that connects to a SOAP service through HTTPS.  This service requires a certificate.  I received the cert form the server in a p12 file, I've added this cert to my default.keystore in worklight.  I added the sslCertificateAllias in the adapter.xml.  When I go to run the adapter I get an error saying it was unable to locate the certificate chain.

The Error

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: FWLSE0152E: Unable to find certificate chain with alias: 'MyAlias' [project OhPleaseWork]"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

The Adapter.xml

```
    <sslCertificateAlias>MyAlias</sslCertificateAlias> 
    <sslCertificatePassword>changeit</sslCertificatePassword>
```

The keystore is located in server/conf along with the properties file.  I ran the keytool -list on the keystore and the alias was listed.  The server file is specific to each application, is there something I am missing about adding this to the "Worklight Development Server."  Thank you for you help!

Comment: are you using your own custom Certification Authority (CA), or do you know if your certificate is signed by an intermediate CA?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define sslCertificateAllias only in case mutual SSL connection, in your scenario you have only one way SSL connection so you needn't to define sslCertificateAllias for your adapter, just remove or comment out it in adapter XML.
Morover, make sure that you received your backend SOAP server certificate using a SSL tool like open SSL, but not by browser like mozilla etc.